# checkbox to disable/enable input

Tags: javascript

I am using js to , onclick of a checkbox, it enables or disables text input.

It works, until I put it into a live form with google jquery api.

Weird but.. must be a conflict somewhere.

The form element is: ( code isnt adding to this post properly )

```
<input type="checkbox" name="others" onclick="enable_text(this.checked)" class="medium" /></div>
```

Name on credit card if different from above

The js is:

```
function enable_text(status)
{
status=!status;
document.form1.other_name.disabled = status;
}
```

What am I doing wrong, I have used body onload handler.

```
<body onload=enable_text(false);>
```

JS FIDDLE : http://www.jsfiddle.net/ozzy/H8VPY/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, a jQuery solution:

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    $("input:text").attr("disabled", !this.checked); 
});
```

Just replace these generic selectors with your more specific ones.

In addition to this code, you will probably also want to make the text-box disabled (initially).

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" />
```

**Working demo:** http://www.jsfiddle.net/H8VPY/11/

Comment: I want the form element to be editable when ticked, disabled when not ticked

Comment: works great, chosen as answer, but need to attribute to specific ID. I will sort that thanks

Comment: Still struggling to apply this to the input ID, we must specify the ID, otherwise other input fields remain disabled/enabled

Comment: @422 Use the ID selector: `$("#textboxID").attr(...);`

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems in your jsfiddle demo.

- The `<script>` and the comment there around should be removed.
- A `<form name="form1">` is missing which caused `document.form1` to return nothing.
- The *onLoad* option on left menu should be a *no wrap (head)* since it's just a function.

Updated demo: http://www.jsfiddle.net/PPZYm/

Comment: Adding the disabled="disabled" attribute to the text-box will suffice. That way, the text-box will initially be disabled.

Comment: @Šime: Yes, can also, if that's the *actual* intent. I only wonder why the OP didn't include it in his own demo.

Comment: Apologies for confusion, I had stripped some code to make it simpler and inadvertantly cocked it up. @Sime your code works A1 thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**[Live Example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/H8VPY/13/)**

```
function enable_text(status) {
    status = (status) ? false : true; //convert status boolean to text 'disabled'
    document.form1.other_name.disabled = status;
}
```

---

**Note**

You also need to wrap your `div` in the jsfiddle example with a `<form>` tag with the name `form1` for it to properly work

```
<div class="controlset-pad">
    <input type="checkbox" name="others" onclick="enable_text(this.checked)" class="medium" />
</div>
<form name="form1">
    <div class="field4">
        <label>Name on credit card if different from above</label><input type="text" name="other_name" class="medium" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I need the element to be disabled until ticked

Comment: You don't need that first line in the function body. `... = !status;` works just fine.

Comment: thanks but, disabled="disabled" remains disabled when we run it